# arduino rfid with led, code is compiling but not working as expected!

Tags: arduino-uno, led, rfid

code is compiling, what I want is that when rfid tag kept led should get on but instead its getting to the else loop.

```
int count = 0;
char input[12]; // rfid input
int led = 3; // led pin
char first[20] = {"270059204B15"}; //rfid tag no
char a[24];


void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(led, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  if (Serial.available() > 0) // code for rfid input
  { count = 0;
    while (Serial.available() && count < 12)
    {
      input[count] = Serial.read();
      count++;
      delay(10);
    }
    Serial.print(input);
  }

  if (strcmp(input, first) == 0) /*comparing two string rfid tag no and input
   if matches led is on*/
  {
    digitalWrite(led, LOW); /* as the board which we are using is in sink
    mode low is taken as 1 or on*/
    delay(500);
    Serial.print("led is on\n");
  }

  else
  { digitalWrite(led, HIGH);
    delay(500);
    Serial.print("led is off\n");
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you clarify your question, provide step by step explanation on how you want it to work(or how you expected it as per title)? Something like a program flow.

Answer (score 2):

Your unespecified problems are consecuence of a collection of small details.

1. You are not putting a binary zero to end the input string.
2. That's not the way to read serial input.
3. Code doesn't filter out control caracteres (LF, CR).

Here is your code cleaned up:

```
#define ID_SIZE 12

int count=0;
char input[ID_SIZE + 1]; // rfid input
int led=3; // led pin
char first[ID_SIZE + 1]= {"270059204B15"}; //rfid tag no

void setup()
{
    // put your setup code here, to run once:
    Serial.begin(9600);
    pinMode(led,OUTPUT);
}

void loop()
{

    // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
    while(Serial.available() > 0 && count < 12) {  // code for rfid input
       char c = Serial.read();
       if (isAlphaNumeric(c)) {
          input[count++]=c;
          }
      }

    input[count] = 0;
    if(count >= 12) {
        Serial.print(input);
    }

    if(strcmp(input,first)==0) /*comparing two string rfid tag no and input
   if matches led is on*/
    {
        digitalWrite(led,LOW); /* as the board which we are using is in sink
    mode low is taken as 1 or on*/
        delay(500);
        Serial.println("led is on\n");
        input[0] = count = 0;
    }

    else {
        digitalWrite(led,HIGH);
        delay(500);
        Serial.println("led is off\n");
    }
}
```

And here is the result:

[image]

Edit:

The C strings are char arrays of undefined lenght. To signal the end of the string, put a binary zero next to the (effective) last element. Then, if you want to store a 10 chars string, you need an 11 elements arrays (10 for the string itself, 1 for the binary zero).

Failure to put a binary zero at the end of a string is a very common cause of program failure.

Control characters. In general, when you type "TEST" in the Serial Monitor and press SEND, what Arduino receive is the word TEST itself, plus a Line Feed/Carriage Return pair (LF/CR) to mark the end of the line.

In real world, your serial input can be *contaminated* with tabs, spaces, LF/CR and other valid chars. You need to discard them (unless they are valid for your app).

Comment: coding service? :-)

Comment: Programming School. The OP, while a beginner, looks in the right path. At least he doesn't use `String` and know about arrays. Posting the original code and the improved version help others to learn better coding practices. Coding Service is coding from scratch on specs. Not this case, the guy did his homework.

Comment: Thank you for your answer alterno, could you please explain your second and third point.

Comment: @NikhilNaidu. I edited my answer.